# React Native. ScrollView Height

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to set the height of my scroll view to 72.5% of the screen height. If I put a border around, I can see that the border indicates that this is correct. However, if I insert something into the ScrollView, the element inside is much smaller than expected. It's height is also proportional (22%). The more things I enter into the ScrollView, the larger these elements get (i.e. the contents of the scroll view is getting bigger and hence the elements inside are scaling). I don not want this, I want the elemetns to be 22% of the fixed 72.5%. I tried inserting a View that was 100% of the scroll height (although the border shows it to render as less), I've tried various different wrapping Views and tried setting height to the scrollView directly, but none of these have seemed to fix it. Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
<View style={{ width: "100%", height: "72.5%", flexDirection: "column" }}>
   <View style={{width:"100%", height:"100%"}}>     
     <ScrollView  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{ width: "100%", height:"100%", flexDirection: "column" ,borderWidth:2}}>
         <View style={{width:"100%", height:"100%", borderWidth:2}}>
             <Bio height={"22%"} plays={10} audience={10} ownUsername={"TestUser"}/>
             <Bio height={"22%"} plays={10} audience={10} ownUsername={"TestUser"}/>
         </View>
     </ScrollView>
   </View> 
 </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your question, but if it's what I think it is... Check out [React Native Documentation on contentContainerStyle of a ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle)